# Proving and finding a limit of two variables

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find out if the next limit exists and what is its value:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{|y|^{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+|\frac{y}{x}|}}.$$

My attempt is based in use polar coordinates, but at the end I have a limit with numerator $r^{r}$ and denominator $\sqrt{r^2+\tan{\theta}},$ but the struggle is on numerator because this limit doesn't exists. Also I was trying to get a bound for the expression, however don't achieve to have a bound for $|y|^{|x|}.$

Any ideas to attack the problem? I have the feeling that the limit value is zero.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The limit $\lim_{r\to 0^+} r^r$ exists. It is one.

Comment: Yes, you're right @Tunococ!! The trick e^(ln) solve this. Thanks a lot!!